# Connot find runtime 'node' on PATH. Vscode Python

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code

I installed visual studio code to practice python.

After I played around with settings now I cannot debug anything. Getting the error:

[image]

I deleted everything from setting already. 
I also tried to reinstall vscode.

But nothing helps.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is node.js installed on your computer? When you install node, there's an option to 'Add to PATH'. Make sure you tick that.

In case you've already installed node and the PATH isn't set. Go to environment variables and add the path to your node.exe installation(usually "C:\Program Files\Nodejs")

Comment: Why does the OP need to install NodeJS when the aim is to practice Python?